# Catia V5 macro getting name of part where axis system is in

Tags: vba, catia

I want to get the name of the part where the axis system is in that I found using the following macro script:

```
'build query string
Dim sQuery
sQuery = "CatPrtSearch.AxisSystem.Visibility=Visible,all"

Dim Selection
Set Selection =CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection  
Selection.Search sQuery
```

But I can't find a way to find the name of the part where the axis systems are in. Does someone have any idea on how I can get that information without user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim sQuery
sQuery = "CatPrtSearch.AxisSystem.Visibility=Visible,all"

Dim Selection
Set Selection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection  
Selection.Search sQuery

for i = 1 to Selection.Count2
   MsgBox Selection.Item2(i).Document.Name 'name of document  
   MsgBox Selection.Item2(i).LeafProduct.Name 'name of instance product  
next
```